# Drawing docking window frames on Vista and up

Tags: winapi

I need to port some old code which implements docking windows in plain C to Vista and up. When dragging docking windows around, the old code draws the docking window's outline directly to the desktop DC by doing something like this:

```
hdc = GetDCEx(NULL, NULL, DCX_WINDOW|DCX_CACHE|DCX_LOCKWINDOWUPDATE);
...
PatBlt(hdc, left, top, width, height, PATINVERT);
...
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

This still works on Vista and up but it is very, very slow - probably, because the DWM has to copy the desktop's frame buffer into a temporary mutable pixel buffer, do the drawing, and copy it back to the now immutable frame buffer. This is very slow.

Thus, I was wondering how such code should be ported to Vista and up. AFAIK, drawing directly to the desktop DC is no longer recommended with the introduction of the DWM in Vista so I was wondering how I should draw my docking windows' outline when the user is dragging them? What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking of abusing cursor images (or drag images or whatever Win32 has on offer here) to do what I want but I'm not sure whether this is really the best way to go. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A transparent overlay window (`WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_POPUP`) may work, if you only need it to follow the mouse cursor, and not for hit-testing.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does the trick! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.